# Installing vmware/xenserver on a linux operating system?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi

We're currently in the process of setting up a server here in a research environment. It would be ideal to use VMware ESXi, but (and I apologise if I get this completely wrong, I'm somewhat new to this) that needs to be installed on the machine initially instead of an OS correct? and then operating systems are installed as virtual machines? However the free version of it isn't suitable for us, the limitations on RAM would make the money we spent on the server redundant. We also looked at Cirtix XenServer free, which apparently has an upper RAM limit of 256GB, which again isn't enough (We have 512GB of RAM, over 4 CPUs which have 16 cores each). Now am I correct in assuming these virtualisation tools cannot be installed over an OS? Because it would be useful to install some linux based operating system on the server, which would have access to the full machine which we can log onto when running particularly intensive programs, but also have a number of virtual machines set up for other people to log into?

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just install CentOS with KVM as virt technology. That way, single VMs are limited to 32TB RAM each, while the base OS is limited only by what Linux can do. And next time, consider license costs up front when planning to buy such a machine.

Comment: What specific CPU models do you have?

Comment: As @SvW mentions, KVM will do what you want. Red Hat has some [great documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/) on setting this up. The same documentation will work on CentOS.

Comment: Of course you are not limited to CentOS with KVM. Many distributions are suitable as KVM hosts like ubunut or debain (if you like them more)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A licensed copy of VMware ESXi, including vCenter (the [Essentials Pack](http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/en_US/DisplayProductDetailsPage/productID.233860600)) is $500-$600US. There's no RAM limit, and it could accommodate up to three hosts.

Given the specifications of your physical hardware, the cost of obtaining the right VMware licensing is negligible.

***Do the right thing!!***

[image]

Comment: Essentials is limited to 2 CPUs per host. OP has ("over"?) 4.

Comment: You can divide the license however you wish. Essentials provides 6 physical CPU socket's worth of licensing. Four of them can be applied to one four-socket host, or you can use six single-socket hosts. It all works.

Comment: Edit. Nevermind! I just read the other comments. This looks great! Can I ask though, why pick VMware over oracle, which is completely free with no restrictions, and according to the oracle website is better at everything? http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/comparisons/index.html

Comment: @TheFoxx The licenses can be split and divided. You have a maximum of three hosts that can be managed under that license. That could be a quad-socket machine and two single-socket systems, or three dual-sockets systems. This is [**documented and supported**](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1290802#1290802), as I do the same on some systems.

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks. I just edited my question though, I'm wondering now how vmware ESXi compares to Oracle server? According to the oracle website, it seems much better, but obviously that might not be the most trustworthy source...

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with the Essentials SKU. I just saw that it says "Max 2 processors per host" on the link you provided.

Comment: @TheFoxx Marketshare. *I* don't know anyone who uses Oracle Virtualization. I know lots of organizations who use VMware. Mindshare and marketshare count for something.

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks, you've been really helpful! However VMware only allows 6 cores per processor in the essentials range? http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/multicore.html They don't even have an option for a 16 core processor. Their licencing is very hard to discern :/ Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @TheFoxx Look at [**this screenshot**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nsLhE.png) from an Essentials setup. It's no longer an issue. Also see the table posted in my answer.

Comment: @ewwhite Cool thanks. I did just post this thread on the VMware site, and according to them the 6 CPU licences can't be divided the way that you said? That it's a max of 2 per host http://communities.vmware.com/thread/454096

Comment: Good luck, then. I'm telling you what works. http://communities.vmware.com/message/1290802#1290802

Comment: Thanks, tbh I'll probably just end up getting in contact with the company tomorrow morning, hopefully that'll straighten things out. In the thread you've shown there it mentions v3.5 maybe VMware have changed it since? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. It works. I have setups running the configuration.